# Matching server configuration with many production flavors

Tags: android, gradle

I develop android app to work with some server infrastructure.
Now there is a 3 server infrastructures called serv1, serv2, serv3 (in this example).
Also I have 8 product flavors (flav1, flav2, ... flav8) and that number may be increased.

Server configuration such as domain and port are stored in `ServerConfig.java`.
Each flavor have ServerConfig java file with corresponding server infrastructure configuration:

```
├ app/src
|   ├ flav1/java/app/package/name/ServerConfig.java //config for serv1
|   ├ flav2/java/app/package/name/ServerConfig.java //config for serv1
|   ├ flav3/java/app/package/name/ServerConfig.java //config for serv2
|   ├ flav4/java/app/package/name/ServerConfig.java //config for serv3
|   ├ flav5/java/app/package/name/ServerConfig.java //config for serv2
|   ├ flav6/java/app/package/name/ServerConfig.java //config for serv3
|   ├ flav7/java/app/package/name/ServerConfig.java //config for serv1
|   └ flav8/java/app/package/name/ServerConfig.java //config for serv3
```

And that works fine but, IMHO, there is to many duplicated code.

Now I have to add crt file for HTTPS verifications. I don't want to apk file contains all 3 crt files.
So I think about creating one directory per server configuration:

```
├ app/src/main/java/app/package/name
├ app/server
|    ├ serv1
|    |   ├ ServerConfig.java
|    |   └ ca.crt
|    ├ serv2
|    |   ├ ServerConfig.java
|    |   └ ca.crt
|    ├ serv3
|    |   ├ ServerConfig.java
|    |   └ ca.crt
```

And use build.gradle to copy configuration and crt to source main location.

```
android {
    productFlavors.whenObjectAdded { flavor ->
        flavor.ext.set('serverType', 'serv1') //serv1/serv2/serv3
    }
    productFlavors {
        flav1 {
            serverType = 'serv1'
        }
        flav1 {
            serverType = 'serv2'
        }
        ...
        flav8 {
            serverType = 'serv3'
        }
    }
}
afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
              if(flavor.serverType.contains("serv1"){
              //add dependency to copy task to pre + variant.name + Build 
              //to copy serv1 config and crt from app/server/serv1 to app/src/main/java/app/package/name
              }
              ...
        }
    }
}
```

A big disadvantage of this solution is hard-coded locations for coping and pasting. So every refactorization of ServerConfig and ca.crt (eg rename) have to change build.gradle file.

Is there a better solution for matching server configurations (ServerConfig.java and ca.crt) with multiple production flavors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Krish answer was very helpful, but in my case using flavorDimensions resulted in creation of 48 build variants. To reduce list of build variants I combine my proposition (in question of this thread), Krish answer and variantFilter feature.

```
android {
    productFlavors.whenObjectAdded { flavor ->
        flavor.ext.set('serverType', 'serv1') //set serv1 as default value //serv1/serv2/serv3 
    }

    flavorDimensions "flav", "conf"

    productFlavors {
    //===== SERVER CONFIG FLAVORS =====
        serv1 {
            dimension "conf"
        }
        serv2 {
            dimension "conf"
        }
        serv3 {
            dimension "conf"
        }
    //===== CLIENT FLAVORS =====
        flav1 {
            serverType = 'serv1' //have to be one of server config flavours name
            dimension "flav"
        }
        flav1 {
            serverType = 'serv2'
            dimension "flav"
        }
        ...
        flav8 {
            serverType = 'serv3'
            dimension "flav"
        }
    }

    variantFilter { variant ->
        def firstFlav = variant.getFlavors().get(0)
        def secondFlav = variant.getFlavors().get(1)
        if (!firstFlav.serverType.equals(secondFlav.name)) {
            variant.setIgnore(true); //hide variants where serverType mismatch server config flavor
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if flavour can inherit from other one. [Possibility to inherit productFlavor issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183350)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use the folder structure like this with a small change for certificate file,

[image]

And use it with flavorDimensions in gradle.

And add like this in gradle file.

```
flavorDimensions "flav", "conf"

    productFlavors{
        flav1{
            applicationId "com.flav1"
            dimension "flav"
        }

        flav2{
            applicationId "com.flav2"
            dimension "flav"
        }

        serv1{
            dimension "conf"
        }

        serv2{
            dimension "conf"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is the solution what I looking for. I have 3 ca.crt file so I have to copy that files to 8 (more in feature) flavor assets locations. And using base class in my case is useless cause ServerConfig have static final fields with server address etc, there are no default value for that fields.

Comment: I image requirement for changing server address eg. from serv1.domain.com to serv2.domain.com for flav7. Changing only fields in ServerConfig without changing ca.crt by someone who don't know that assets dir in flav7 contain ca.crt may lead to generate production build with big bug. I search scalable solution which allowed to using as few steps as possible to switch server configs.

Comment: @obywatelgcc I have updated my answer, can you check this.

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for, but now I have 8*3*2 = 48 build variants.